# Invalid Method Declaration Return Type Required

Tags: java

The following code gives me error

> Invalid method declaration return type required

```
public void song() {    
    System.out.println("******);   
    System.out.println("******");    
    System.out.println("******");   
    System.out.println("******");
}
song();
```

I am using android studio.

Comment: `song();` after method declaration is certainly in the wrong place.

Comment: Also you have an unterminated string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your class would look like this:

```
public class MyClass{
    public void song() {
        System.out.println("******");
        System.out.println("******");
        System.out.println("******");
        System.out.println("******");
    }
}
```

You cant call `song()` directly from the class body. You have to invoke it from somewhere else. E.g. the `main()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    new MyClass().song();
}
```

Which then prints:

```
******
******
******
******
```